# Get Darker Color by Factor Given Color Int

Tags: java, android, android-color

Here is how I get a Lighter color given an int. But I am wondering how can I convert this to give me a darker color?

How should I modify the method below to give a darker color?

```
public static int getLighterColorByValue(int color, float factor) {
    int red = (int) ((Color.red(color) * (1 - factor) / 255 + factor) * 255);
    int green = (int) ((Color.green(color) * (1 - factor) / 255 + factor) * 255);
    int blue = (int) ((Color.blue(color) * (1 - factor) / 255 + factor) * 255);
    return Color.argb(Color.alpha(color), red, green, blue);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Considering only the red channel (since the logic for the others is identical):

```
int red = (int) ((Color.red(color) * (1 - factor) / 255 + factor) * 255);
```

You are calculating a weighted sum between the current red channel and 255 (full intensity). In simplified terms:

```
int newRed = (1 - factor) * oldRed + factor * 255;
```

So, instead of blending with full intensity, blend with zero intensity:

```
int newRed = (1 - factor) * oldRed + factor * 0;
```

or, more simply:

```
int newRed = (1 - factor) * oldRed;
```

So, using the format of your original code, just drop the `+ factor`:

```
int red = (int) ((Color.red(color) * (1 - factor) / 255) * 255);
```

But since `1 - factor` is a `float`, dividing by 255 and multiplying by 255 gets you back to the same number again. So, more simply:

```
int red = (int) ((Color.red(color) * (1 - factor));
int green = (int) ((Color.green(color) * (1 - factor));
int blue = (int) ((Color.blue(color) * (1 - factor));
```

Sanity check:

- If `factor == 0`, the new color is the same as the original color
- It `factor == 1`, `(1 - factor) == 0`, so `red == green == blue == 0`, i.e. the new color is black.